# Django - display and saving in a simple form

Tags: django, django-views

This is a very beginner-orientated question but I've been stuck on this issue all day.

I would like to load the data for a specific record and be able to save it (Submit button in a template) but i'm still trying to understand instances and the save method.

**models.py**

```
class model_essays(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default='1', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    date_added = models.models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
         return self.title
```

*I understand the id is created automatically*

**forms.py**

```
class frm_essays (forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = model_essays
        fields = ['title', 'date_added', 'body']
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
       path('essay/<int:pk>', views.views_essay),
]
```

**views.py {stuck here}**

```
@login_required
def views_essay(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        updatedForm = essay_detail(request.POST, instance=request.? {I want the ID of the essay})

    if u_form.is_valid():
        updatedForm.save()
        messages.success(request, f'this essay has been updated')
        return redirect('essay_detail')

    else:
        updatedForm = frm_essays(instance=request.{as above})

   context = {
       'updatedForm': updatedForm
}

   return render(request, 'essay_detail.html', context)
```

On the decorator - I haven't gotten around to only allowing the users to view their own created essays, this would be the next large hurdle but not the issue I'm asking about.

Comment: Just a heads up class naming convention in Python is Pascal Case. Django model naming convention is to make the model name singular. You may want to refactor `class model_essays` to `class Essay`. It makes your code just a little more readable and understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken you are looking for the same ID as the `pk` (primary key). You have that passed in as an argument to your function.

You just need to query the instance from the DB.

```py
def views_essay(request, pk):
    essay = model_essays.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        updatedForm = essay_detail(request.POST, instance=essay)
    ...
```

Note: `essay` will be `None` if the query based on the `pk` does not find an match in the DB.